# Yarn 3: Hybrid node_modules & pnp - How do local dependencies work?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2

I followed the instructions for *Hybrid PnP + node_modules mono-repo:* from the [Recipes](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/recipes).

Does that support referencing other packages in the same repository from the workspace for which the `node-modules` linker is enabled?

Whenever I provide the `yarn.lock` file as instructed, local packages cannot be resolved any more:

```
➤ YN0001: │ Error: @local/lib@workspace:^: Workspace not found (@local/lib@workspace:^)
    at St.getWorkspaceByDescriptor (C:\Users\Max\repos\yarn-pnp-react-native\.yarn\releases\yarn-4.0.2.cjs:210:3520)
```

Sample repository here: [yarn-pnp-react-native](https://github.com/mxro/yarn-pnp-react-native/tree/master)

Note when configuring the repository as suggested in https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/4232 local dependencies are resolved correctly. However, then when running `yarn` in the `node-modules` linked workspaces, `node_module` resolution is provided for all workspaces (which I understand as per #4323 to be the intended behaviour).

In any case, I can see only the following options:

- *Do not provide a yarn.lock*: Local dependency resolution works, but one gets `node_modules` all over when running `yarn install` from the wrong place
- *Provide a yarn.lock*: `node-modules` linker isolated to provided project, but local dependency resolution does not work

Both of these don't solve the requirement of local dependency resolution without 'leaking' the `node-modules` linker into the other workspaces. Is that possible?